# I cant make the "else" function to work properly

Tags: python

No matter what `cpu` input is, it always prints `"CPU FOUND"`

```
cpu = input("CPU: ")

if cpu == "Ryzen 9 5950X" or "i9-10900K" or "i9-10900KF":
    print("CPU FOUND")
else:
    print("CPU NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: It's not a problem with `else`, it's a problem with `or "some string"`. `cpu == "Ryzen 9 5950X" or "i9-10900K"` is not the same as `cpu == "Ryzen 9 5950X" or cpu == "i9-10900K"`.

Comment: you could do `if any(cpu == i for i in ["Ryzen 9 5950X", "i9-10900K", "i9-10900KF"])`